# Converting from FromLambdaExpression to CreateModelExpression and having issues

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have the following snippet of code,

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CIDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string modelName)
    {
        TagBuilder containerDivBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
        if (modelName == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("modelName"); }
        ModelState modelState = helper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
        ModelErrorCollection modelErrors = (modelState == null) ? null : modelState.Errors;
        ModelError modelError = ((modelErrors == null) || (modelErrors.Count == 0)) ? null : modelErrors[0];

        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

        if (metadata.IsRequired)
        {
         //Code goes here
        }
```

}

and I am trying to upgrade to .net core 3.0 but having issues on how to use ModelExpression.  I tried several approaches but I am obviosly missing something.  In any case, this is my latest attempt.

```
    public static IHtmlContent CIDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> selectList, string modelName)
    {

        if (modelName == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("modelName"); }
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateEntry modelState = helper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelErrorCollection modelErrors = (modelState == null) ? null : modelState.Errors;
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelError modelError = ((modelErrors == null) || (modelErrors.Count == 0)) ? null : modelErrors[0];

        IModelExpressionProvider meta;


        meta.CreateModelExpression(helper.ViewData, expression);
            if (meta.IsRequired)
        {
         //Code goes here
        }
```

An example code would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, if you found an answer to your question can you please post the answer? I don't find any solution for this issue.